# XML file validated by two schemas

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I want to create an XML file that should be validated by two schemas (one import another):

```
<bbb:Order xmlns:bbb="http://NamespaceTest.com/BBB" xmlns:aaa="http://NamespaceTest.com/AAA">
  <aaa:Customer>
    <aaa:Name>string</aaa:Name>
    <aaa:DeliveryAddress>string</aaa:DeliveryAddress>
    <aaa:BillingAddress>string</aaa:BillingAddress>
  </aaa:Customer>
</bbb:Order>
```

For this, I have created two schemas. First one looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://NamespaceTest.com/AAA"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns="http://NamespaceTest.com/AAA"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="Customer" type="CustomerType">
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="CustomerType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="DeliveryAddress" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="BillingAddress" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

and I import this file into the second schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://NamespaceTest.com/BBB"
           xmlns:aa="http://NamespaceTest.com/AAA" targetNamespace="http://NamespaceTest.com/BBB"
           elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:import schemaLocation="aaa.xsd" namespace="http://NamespaceTest.com/AAA"/>
    <xs:element name="Order">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Customer" type="aa:CustomerType"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

When I have such schemas, the element Customer in the XML file must be referenced from namespace http://NamespaceTest.com/BBB, but I want it to be referenced from http://NamespaceTest.com/AAA (where the type is defined). How the schema should be changed so I can have the XML like at the beginning of the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined a local element `bbb:Customer` when you should have referenced the global element `aaa:Customer`. It should be

```
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="aa:Customer"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Incidentally (and a lot of people get the terminology wrong, you're not alone) you have one schema here, made up of two schema documents.